# CSS Menu Working Inconsistently on iOS

Tags: ios, css

I have a CSS menu that isn't working consistently on iOS (8).  Most of the time when I click the menu bar nothing happens.  It will work about 30% of the time.  Sometimes it won't work and then after a page refresh it works again.

I've checked in web inspector and everything looks like it should be working.

You can test it here:
http://bit.ly/1zy5Tmf

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've actually noticed that if you go straight to a product page (i.e. using the link above) the menu works fine.  However if you go to a product page via (i.e http://bit.ly/1B3tcbu) a category page it doesn't seem to work.

I am testing on an iPhone 6, 8.13.

Comment: Tested on 8.1.2 (4S) and works fine.  I would check if click function is firing properly by attaching alert to it and if not, check if element dimensions and/or visibility/z-indexes are correct

Comment: Tested on 8.1.3 (iPad 3/retina) working fine on all links in several categories.

Comment: Tested on 8.1.3 (5S) via both links the menu works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tested on an iPhone 6 8.1.3 and the menu works great. Since @jacek_podwysocki, @Simon Mason, and @Jayx also tested with positive results, it seems that this is an issue on your specific device.

I was, however, able to find information on the subject: http://www.shdon.com/blog/2013/06/07/why-your-click-events-don-t-work-on-mobile-safari

You said that it works after a page refresh. That sounds like a cache issue. Have you tried clearing the cache? Go to Settings>Safari>Advanced>Remove All Website Data. That should hopefully have everything running smoothly again.

Comment: Hi.  Yeah, I tried refreshing cache but the problem persists.  It is really strange.....it will work initially but after I browse a few pages it will suddenly stop.  Seems like it is more likely to stop on a product page but it is inconsistent.

Comment: Any scripts that could be causing the issue?

Comment: Not that I can think of.  The menu should be purely css and seems to work most of the time.  Once it stops working then I need to relaunch Safari (mobile) to get it working again.  I've checked in web inspector and I can see the css changing so the menu should display but it just doesn't.

Comment: I've tried different networks and the problem persists.  I've tested on older iPhones and couldn't replicate the issue.

Comment: I think it's just your iPhone. Have you reset all Safari settings or tried a full restore?